# Can't type non-latin symbols in absolutely positioned HTML input on Android(PhoneGap)

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

i've faced some strange problem with absolutely positioned divs and text inputs.
For example(just some short snipped):

```
<div><input value="normal"/></div>
<div style="position: absolute;"><input value="positioned"/></div>
```

The trick here is that you can easily input any symbol in 'normal' field but you can't do this in 'positioned' field - for example, you could type english text but danish or japan letters are just ignored...

Has anyone solved similar problem?

P.S. It's tested on PhoneGap

**UPD.** More tests tells that problem is somehow bounded with focus problem on 'positioned' element.

Comment: Using Android 2.3.5, I don’t see any problem with entering Danish, Greek etc. characters, when using the exact markup you posted.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thx for testing. I'll dig deeper to find where is the problem... because my real page is more complicated than given snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i don't know why but the problem was in this css rule

```
html, body{-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; /* Force webkit to use sub-pixel antialiasing */}
```